# Why does django url tag with argument work in VS Code but not Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have a simple django app built in Visual Studio 2019 using python.
I am trying to use a url template tag to open a record in a form on another page in order to update that record but it always returns: 'reverse not found...'

This is the template tag (uform.id is the argument):

```
<td><a href="{% url 'app:form-update' uform.id %}">{{ obj.form_name }}</a></td>
```

The url paths:

```
from django.urls import path
from app import views

app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home, name='home'),
path('form-create/', views.create_form, name='form_create'),
path('form-update/<str:pk>/', views.updateForm, name='form-update'),
]
```

The view:

```
def updateForm(request, pk):
uform = Forms.objects.get(id=pk)
form = FormRegisterForm(instance=uform)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = FormRegisterForm(request.POST, instance=uform)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('app:form_register')
context = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'app/form_create.html', context)
```

When I replace the id argument in the url template tag with an id such as 19, it works without error.  This suggests the syntax of the url template tag is wrong, however the same syntax works in other apps I have created using VS Code.  I don't understand why it won't work in Visual Studio 2019.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass `uform` to the template:

```
def updateForm(request, pk):
    uform = Forms.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormRegisterForm(request.POST, instance=uform)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('app:form_register')
    else:
        form = FormRegisterForm(instance=uform)
    context = {'form': form, 'uform': uform}
    return render(request, 'app/form_create.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it still results in:
Reverse for 'form-update' with arguments '('',)' not found.

Comment: @MichaelPiraner: what is the template where you use this template tag.

Comment: @ Willem Van Olsen: it is the form_register.html